# Approximation of $\frac{1}{a}$ with Newton-Raphson

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

**Approximation of $\frac{1}{a}$ with Newton-Raphson**

To start the method we search an equation $F(x)$ of which $\frac{1}{a}$ is a solution.

My book uses the equation: $F(x)=\frac{1}{x}-a=0$

But why can't you use the equations:

- $F(x)=x-\frac{1}{a}=0$
- $F(x)=ax-1=0$

Answer (score 1):

- For your first proposition to compute $F(x)$ you need to know $\frac{1}{a}$, but the goal of the method is precisely to know this number as the sequence write:
  $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n-1/a}{1}=x_n-x_n+\frac{1}{a}$$
- For the second one there is actually the same problem as tour sequence write:
  $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{ax_n-1}{a}=x_n-x_n+\frac{1}{a}$$

(For linear function Newton method is simply to solve the problem in one step).

---

As a side note with the function proposed:
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{1/x-a}{-1/x^2}=x_n+x_n-ax_n^2$$
so you only need to use number that you actually know before.

Comment: To make this a little clearer: to use Newton-Raphson on either of the functions proposed in the OP, you have to already know what $\frac 1a$ is. And if you do, why are you trying to estimate it? If you only have an estimate to $\frac 1a$, then these two methods will never improve it - they just give the same estimate back. But the function the book chose doesn't require knowing how to divide by $a$ at all. Only subtraction and multiplication are used in its recursion. It will improve any positive estimate of $\frac 1a$ with each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Try them! They update an arbitrary root estimate to $1/a$, presupposing knowledge of the reciprocal.